# Php string interpolation

Tags: php

How does string interpolation work in this scenario?
i'm not sure if i'm making a syntax error or not.

i'm trying to get the amount of items in this `return`

```
return "Your collection exists of {count($this->movies)} movies.";
```

when i try this it says:
"PHP Warning:  Array to string conversion"

Comment: String interpolation does not work with functions. You'll need to break out of the string to use `count()`

Comment: Why not run the code and check what happens? PHP would tell you pretty clear if there was a syntax error

Comment: Entirely unrelated note: "exists of" is not correct English, it should be "consists of".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string interpolation rules are [described thoroughly in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). Importantly, there are two main styles:

- One with plain variables in the string, like `"the $adjective apple"`, which also supports *some* expressions like `$foo->bar` in `"the $foo->bar apple"`
- One with curly brackets, which supports more complex expressions, like `{$foo->bar()}`, but the expression *must* start with a `$`

When PHP sees your string:

- it first sees `{count(`, but because the character after `{` isn't `$`, it doesn't mean anything special
- it *then* sees the `$this->movies`, which is valid for the *first* syntax, so it tries to output `$this->movies` as a string
- because `$this->movies` is an array, you get a Warning and the string `"Array"` is used

The result is that the string will always say `"Your collection exists of {count(Array} movies."`.

---

There is no interpolation syntax currently that supports function calls like `count()`, so you'll have to use concatenation or an intermediate variable:

```
return "Your collection exists of " . count($this->movies) . " movies.";
```

or

```
$movieCount = count($this->movies);
return "Your collection exists of {$movieCount} movies.";
```

or

```
$movieCount = count($this->movies);
return "Your collection exists of $movieCount movies.";
```

Comment: Or implement a method ```getMovieCount(): int``` and use ```"... of $this->getMovieCount() movies."```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a PHP var inside a string which is wrapped by double quoutes. But it is not possible with a function. 2 possible ways to do it:

```php
$this->movies = ['lethal weapon 1','lethal weapon 9'];
$count = count($this->movies);
return "Your collection exists of $count movies.";
```

**or**

```php
$this->movies = ['austin powers 1','austin powers 2'];
return "Your collection exists of " . count($this->movies) . " movies.";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try following line

```
return "Your collection exists of {".count($this->movies)."} movies.";
```

Comment: the {} brackets are not supposed to be part of the string but of the string interpolation method OP tried to use...